# Fetching data from MySQL database using PHP, Displaying it in a form for editing

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm a newbie to this and wrote the code below to fetch user data from a MySQL Database and display it in a form for editing and saving. Problem is, it does not work. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Delegate edit form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Delegate update form  <p>
            <?php
            $usernm   = "root";
            $passwd   = "";
            $host     = "localhost";
            $database = "swift";

            //$Name=$_POST['Name'];
            //$Username=$_POST['User_name'];
            //$Password=$_POST['Password'];

            mysql_connect($host,$usernm,$passwd);

            mysql_select_db($database);

            $sql    = "SELECT * FROM usermaster WHERE User_name='$Username'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            while ($row    = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {

                $Name     = $row['Name'];
                $Username = $row['User_name'];
                $Password = $row['User_password'];
            }
            ?>
        <form action="Delegate_update.php" method="post">
            Name
            <input type="text" name= "Name" value= "<?php echo $row ['Name']; ?> "size=10>
            Username
            <input type="text" name= "Username" value= "<?php echo $row ['Username']; ?> "size=10>
            Password
            <input type="text" name= "Password" value= "<?php echo $row ['Password']; ?>" size=17>
            <input type="submit" name= "submit" value="Update">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What error do you get? What have you done to troubleshoot this?

Comment: use mysqli instead of mysql wherever possible

Comment: You dont close your form tag, so how is it supposed to know what form it should post

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Play around this piece of code. Focus on the concept, edit where necessary so that it can

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Delegate edit form</title>
</head>
<body>
    Delegate update form  </p>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />


    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif|Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/flexslider/flexslider.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/basic-style.css">




    <script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body id="home">

        <header class="wrapper clearfix">



            <nav id="topnav" role="navigation">
                <div class="menu-toggle">Menu</div>
                <ul class="srt-menu" id="menu-main-navigation">
                    <li><a href="Swift_Landing.html">Home page</a></li>

        </header>
        </section>

        <style>
            form label {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 100px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
        </ul>

        <?php
        session_start();
        $usernm="root";
        $passwd="";
        $host="localhost";
        $database="swift";

        $Username=$_SESSION['myssession'];



        mysql_connect($host,$usernm,$passwd);

        mysql_select_db($database);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usermaster WHERE User_name='$Username'";
        $result = mysql_query ($sql) or die (mysql_error ());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)){

        ?>

        <form action="Delegate_update.php" method="post">
            Name
            <input type="text" name="Namex" value="<?php echo $row ['Name']; ?> " size=10>
            Username
            <input type="text" name="Username" value="<?php echo $row ['User_name']; ?> " size=10>
            Password
            <input type="text" name="Password" value="<?php echo $row ['User_password']; ?>" size=17>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
        </form>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Appreciate all the help guys, sorry I did not post the error. Will try your suggestions and let you know what worked. Once again thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
<form action="Delegate_update.php" method="post">
Name
<input type="text" name= "Name" value= "<?php echo $row['Name']; ?> "size=10>
Username
<input type="text" name= "Username" value= "<?php echo $row['Username']; ?> "size=10>
Password
<input type="text" name= "Password" value= "<?php echo $row['Password']; ?>" size=17>
<input type="submit" name= "submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

You didnt closed your opening Form in the first place, plus your code is very very messy. I wont go into the "use pdo or mysqli statements, instead of mysql" thats for you to find out on yourself. Also you have a php tag open and close below it, not sure what is needed there. Something else is that your code refers to an external page, which you didnt post, so if something isnt working there, might be handy to post it too.

Please also note that you had spaces between your $row array variables in the form. You have to link those up together by removing the space (see edited section from me). PHP isn't forgiving when it comes to those mistakes.

Then your HTML. I took the liberty to correct that too

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Delegate edit form</title>
    </head>

    <body>
          <p>Delegate update form</p>
<?php
$usernm="root";
$passwd="";
$host="localhost";
$database="swift";

mysql_connect($host,$usernm,$passwd); 
mysql_select_db($database);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM usermaster WHERE User_name='".$Username."'"; // Please look at this too.
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error()); // dont put spaces in between it, else your code wont recognize it the query that needs to be executed
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){     // here too, you put a space between it
    $Name=$row['Name'];
    $Username=$row['User_name'];
    $Password=$row['User_password'];
    }
?>
```

Also, try to be specific. "It doesnt work" doesnt help us much, a specific error type is commonly helpful, plus any indication what the code should do (well, it was kinda obvious here, since its a login/register edit here, but for larger chunks of code it should always be explained)

Anyway, welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: Thank you Dorvalla, i fixed the basic errors in the code (thanks for that) but still get the error " Notice: Undefined variable: Username in D:\wamp\www\Swift_Registration\Delegate_edit.php on line 17". Once again, i'm new to PHP/MySQL so forgive me for my very basic knowledge.

Comment: `mysql_connect($host,$usernm,$passwd);` is your line 17, if i counted correctly. Appearantly, your username isn't a defined variable. Did you edit somethign there you didnt post in your original post? (else make an edit or so), cause for me, there is no variable named "Username"

Comment: My apologies, i counted in your old post, not in the new one, thus if you take my post its indeed a different name. The variale i gave there in order to find your username should correspend with the id you shoot through from your previous page. So either you twist the id towards a name (do a search for that) or simply use the id instead of the username to userid. The Oracle has a part in his code where it is defined, check that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="Delegate_update.php" method="post">
  Name
  <input type="text" name= "Name" value= "<?php echo $row['Name']; ?> "size=10>
  Username
  <input type="text" name= "Username" value= "<?php echo $row['Username']; ?> "size=10>
  Password
  <input type="text" name= "Password" value= "<?php echo $row['Password']; ?>" size=17>
  <input type="submit" name= "submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

look into this

Answer (score 0):

please try these

```
<form action="Delegate_update.php" method="post">
Name
<input type="text" name= "Name" value= "<?php echo $row['Name']; ?> "size=10>
Username
<input type="text" name= "User_name" value= "<?php echo $row['User_name']; ?> "size=10>
Password
<input type="text" name= "User_password" value= "<?php echo $row['User_password']; ?>" size=17>
<input type="submit" name= "submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 include 'cdb.php';
$show=mysqli_query( $conn,"SELECT *FROM 'reg'");


while($row1= mysqli_fetch_array($show)) 

{

                 $id=$row1['id'];
                $Name= $row1['name'];
                $email = $row1['email'];
                $username = $row1['username'];
                $password= $row1['password'];
                $birthm = $row1['bmonth'];
                $birthd= $row1['bday'];
                $birthy= $row1['byear'];
                $gernder = $row1['gender'];
                $phone= $row1['phone'];
                $image=$row1['image'];
}


?>


<html>
<head><title>hey</head></title></head>

<body>

<form>
<table border="-2" bgcolor="pink" style="width: 12px; height: 100px;" >

    <th>
    id<input type="text" name="" style="width: 30px;" value= "<?php echo $row1['id']; ?>"  >
</th>

<br>
<br>

    <th>

 name <input type="text" name=""  style="width: 60px;" value= "<?php echo $row1['Name']; ?>" >
</th>

<th>
 email<input type="text" name="" style="width: 60px;" value= "<?php echo $row1['email']; ?>"  >
</th>
<th>
    username<input type="hidden" name="" style="width: 60px;"  value= "<?php echo $username['email']; ?>" >
</th>
<th>
    password<input type="hidden" name="" style="width: 60px;"  value= "<?php echo $row1['password']; ?>">
</ths>

<th>
    birthday month<input type="text" name="" style="width: 60px;"  value= "<?php echo $row1['birthm']; ?>">
</th>
<th>
   birthday day<input type="text" name="" style="width: 60px;"  value= "<?php echo $row1['birthd']; ?>">
</th>
<th>
       birthday year<input type="text" name="" style="width: 60px;" value= "<?php echo $row1['birthy']; ?>" >
</th>
<th>
    gender<input type="text" name="" style="width: 60px;" value= "<?php echo $row1['gender']; ?>">
</th>
<th>
    phone number<input type="text" name="" style="width: 60px;" value= "<?php echo $row1['phone']; ?>">
</th>
<th>
    <th>
     image<input type="text" name="" style="width: 60px;"  value= "<?php echo $row1['image']; ?>">
</th>

<th>

<font color="pink"> <a href="update.php">update</a></font>

</th>
</table>

</body>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add a description of how your proposed solution actually answers the original question?