# How to do retrieve sql data and display in php page

Tags: php, mysql

i want to retrieve particular cell data from mysql. and it should display in a php page.

details-

db name: register,    table name: users

columns are: username, fullname, email, password.

i want to display 'fullname' column first row data in php. 
how to  do that.

Comment: try searching for `mysqli` or `pdo`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetching data from MySQL database using PHP, Displaying it in a form for editing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174380/fetching-data-from-mysql-database-using-php-displaying-it-in-a-form-for-editing)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

NOTE: `MySql` is deprecated. You should use `MySqli` or `PDO`.

This would help you.

```
$sql = "SELECT fullname FROM users";
$row = mysql_query($sql);

while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($row)){
    echo $data['fullname'];
}
```

Comment: @Dagon : didn't get you.